# Why won't equal trig expressions simplify to the same form?

Tags: simplifying-expressions, trigonometry

Trying to get Mathematica to do trig always stresses the hell out of me ...
Why. won't. it. do. things?!?

Why does

```
Print[Assuming[μ > 0 && g > 0 && ℏ > 0 && m > 0 && k > 0, 
Integrate[(
  4 μ^2 g^2)/(ℏ^4 (m^2 + 4 k^2 Sin[θ/2])^2)
    *emphasized text*Sin[θ], {θ, 0, π}, {ϕ, 0, 2 π}]]] // Simplify;
```

return

```
(2 g^2 π μ^2 (-((4 k^2)/(4 k^2 + m^2)) + Log[1 + (4 k^2)/m^2]))/(k^4 ℏ^4)
```

while using the double angle identity and converting sin into cos

```
Print[Assuming[μ > 0 && g > 0 && ℏ > 0 && m > 0 && k > 0, Integrate[(4 μ^2 g^2)/(ℏ^4 (m^2 + 2 k^2 - 2 k^2 Cos[θ])^2)
  Sin[θ], {θ, 0, π}, {ϕ, 0, 2 π}]]] //
```

returns a much nicer

```
(16 g^2 π μ^2)/((4 k^2 m^2 + m^4) ℏ^4)
```

?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you made a mistake when using double angle identity. In your equations, I got`(2 Sin[θ/2]) == (1 - Cos[θ])`, where it should be `(2 Sin[θ/2]^2) == (1 - Cos[θ])`

```
Assuming[μ > 0 && g > 0 && ℏ > 0 && m > 0 && k > 0, 
Integrate[(4 μ^2 g^2)/(ℏ^4 (m^2 + 4 k^2 Sin[θ/2]^2)^2) Sin[θ], 
  {θ, 0, π}, {ϕ, 0, 2 π}]] // FullSimplify
```

returns

```
(*(16 g^2 π μ^2)/((4 k^2 m^2 + m^4) ℏ^4)*)
```

However, if your first equation is the original, then you probably shouldn't use the identity and take the inelegant answer.

Comment: ack! holy crap, i checked it like ten times X.x ... thanks, sorry for the useless post then >.<